# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleOptionChange' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a number of textboxes generated dynamically from parent component and I want to add a function to its onChange event:

```
const listElements = this.state.controlsToAdd
.map( function(field, index) {
    return (<Control ref={"option" + (index + 1)} key={index + 1} type={field.ControlType} label={field.ControlLabel} localChange={this.handleOptionChange(this, index)} />)
})
```

I keep getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleOptionChange' of undefined

Here is the function itself:

```
handleOptionChange(e, idx) {
var opts = this.state.opts;
opts[idx]={key: idx, name:e.target.value}; 
this.setState({opts: opts});

}
```

What I want to do is whenever a values is typed into one of the input boxes to insert a value into a state array

I bound my function inside the constructor as follows:

> this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);

Modified jsfiddle code:

```
     class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {value: [1,2,3,4], item: ''};
       this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);
  } 
  handleOptionChange(opt){
     console.log(opt);
     this.setState({opt: opt});
  }
 render() {
    return <div>
       Clicked Item: {this.state.item}
    {
       this.state.value.map((i,j)=>{return <input key={j} onChange=   {this.handleOptionChange.bind(this,i)} value={this.state.value[i-1]}/>})
     }
     *Click on any item
    </div> ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a `binding` issue, inside `map` you are using `callback` method, so you have to maintain the `context` also by using `.bind(this)` with `callback` method, or you can use `arrow function`, it will do this job for you, You can use `arrow function` like this:

```
const listElements = this.state.controlsToAdd
.map((field, index)=>{
    return (<Control ref={"option" + (index + 1)} key={index + 1} type={field.ControlType} label={field.ControlLabel} localChange={this.handleOptionChange.bind(this, index)} />)
})
```

Or use callback method like this:

```
const listElements = this.state.controlsToAdd
    .map(function(field, index){
        return (<Control ref={"option" + (index + 1)} key={index + 1} type={field.ControlType} label={field.ControlLabel} localChange={this.handleOptionChange.bind(this, index)} />)
    }.bind(this))
```

Check the working example on `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/3erwnxfk/

Comment: the first option gave me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error

Comment: this means `controlsToAdd` is not defined in component state, check where you declare this, and it should be any array

Comment: check the sample working code, write ur code in a similar way, it will work :)

Comment: I slightly modified your code to suit my needs: I need input boxes instead of paragraphs and instead of onClick - onChange. So it looks good but the values in the input boxes are read only. I need to be able to change them. Also the array `value` will be filled dynamically and so should start out as empty

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/mtbg3g59/ n no of input fields with separate state variable and onchange handling :) similarly you can handle ur case also. please mark the answer as correct, it solved ur prblm :)

Comment: glad to help you :)